# Using Embed api to local dashboard

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-my-business-api

I want to fetch and show gmb insights in my local dashboard. So, in order to do so i first linked Google My Business to google analytics and then I want to use embed api.
Is this correct or any better way i can establish a link?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Question is too vague, show some code, how do you want to embed it, just plain php? or JS ?

Comment: I can use php and js

Comment: Basically i want suggestions...is there any other way of showing gmb insights on local website.

Comment: can't you use this API? https://developers.google.com/my-business/content/insight-data

Comment: no, I want all of my data (views and searches) to be shown on providing accountid. But using above api the data will be location specific